# implement permissions on extension Bolt CMS (Silex)

Tags: bolt-cms

I want my extension to notice that you have permission, in documenting bolt talking about $ app ['user'] -> isAllowed (), is there any example of how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of method *isAllowed()* can be very different based on purpose.

One of possible is here in extension Editable: http://bit.ly/1teHdS9

More detailed description can be found in Doccode:

```
/**
 * Runs a permission check. Permissions are encoded as strings, where
 * the ':' character acts as a separator for dynamic parts and
 * sub-permissions.
 * Apart from the route-based rules defined in permissions.yml, the
 * following special cases are available:
 *
 * "overview:$contenttype" - view the overview for the content type. Alias
 *                           for "contenttype:$contenttype:view".
 * "contenttype:$contenttype",
 * "contenttype:$contenttype:view",
 * "contenttype:$contenttype:view:$id" - View any item or a particular item
 *                                       of the specified content type.
 * "contenttype:$contenttype:edit",
 * "contenttype:$contenttype:edit:$id" - Edit any item or a particular item
 *                                       of the specified content type.
 * "contenttype:$contenttype:create" - Create a new item of the specified
 *                                     content type. (It doesn't make sense
 *                                     to provide this permission on a
 *                                     per-item basis, for obvious reasons)
 * "contenttype:$contenttype:change-ownership",
 * "contenttype:$contenttype:change-ownership:$id" - Change the ownership
 *                                of the specified content type or item.
 *
 * @param string $what The desired permission, as elaborated upon above.
 * @return bool TRUE if the permission is granted, FALSE if denied.
 */
```

Since architect of extensions will slightly change in forthcoming v2 *isAllowed()* stays same as before.